# Why is system memory consumption from an IIS application is not released when app pool is recycled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, iis-7, memory-leaks

I'm trying to debug a possible memory leak in one of our production apps.

On our production server, I have a .Net application running in its own app pool.  Recycling the application's app pool and the ASP.Net v4.0 app pool doesn't free up the memory used.

It is only when I restart the IIS server that the memory resources are released.

Wondering why this is, and what are some recommended profiling tools I can use on the server to detect if there is a memory leak?

Also, when I add new binaries (recompile code and add new DLL's to the bin folder) application-level counts reset, but memory doesn't.

Comment: How do you know that the memory is not released? Which process is holding this memory? Is it the process of your application? Are you using unmanaged code?

Comment: I'm monitoring the server's physical memory usage history.  Only when I restart IIS does the consumption fall back down.  The app maintains a collection of several thousand users, so I thought that once the pool was recycled, those memory resources would be released, but they're not - trying to figure it out.

Comment: So it's probably not the app pool that you are thinking that is consuming the memory. Maybe it's some other application?

Comment: I initially thought that, but there is nothing else running on this prod server, and restarting all other app pools did nothing.